# Javascript click Event only Triggers on Page Reload then does not work

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am writing a small practice website. Relevant HTML:

```html
...
<body>
    <div id="button">CLICK ME</div>
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

My app.js file has the following code:

```js
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", new function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

When I reload the page, the event triggers. After that, clicking the `div` does nothing. What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try removing the "new" keyword please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `addEventListener` takes a reference to a function. Putting `new` in front, you create a new object and you apply an anonymous function as constructor. So the return value of it is an *object* instead of a function, which is what you need.

As such, your code would need to be (as pointed out by Met Byrdy):

```
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Just for fun though, I will give you a way to actually use `new` in that context. You can use the `new Function` syntax to do it:

```
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", new Function("alert('dsds')"));
```

Not that I recommend it, but thought you should know there is a way to write a function like that as well.

Reference: https://javascript.info/new-function

Answer (score 2):

insead of  new function() use only function

```
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Could you explain why there's a difference?

Comment: You can checkout the documentation here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

And here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: Can you explain why it fires on load if you leave `new` in front of `function`?

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener takes two arguments, the second argument is the function that you want the listener to invoke every time the event is triggered, in your case "click" event.

When you put "new" in front of the function it changes the function into a constructor function that creates a class instance ( returns an object ).
That is why you need to use the function without the new keyword just like below.

```
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

-- Edit --

You can check this [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript#:%7E:text=The%20new%20keyword%20is%20used,the%20constructor%20function%27s%20prototype%20property)